# Swift: UITextField Delegate is never set, or the methods are never called

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am trying to implement a `UITextFieldDelegate` that performs a certain thing when the user presses return. However, although I set the delegate both from the storyboard and from the `viewDidLoad` method, the delegate methods are never called. Here is my code:

```
/*UITextFieldDelegate*/
@IBOutlet weak var messageTextField: UITextField!
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {    //delegate method

}

func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {  //delegate method
    return false
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {   //delegate method
    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    //check if message isn't empty
    if let _ = textField.text?.isEmpty {

    } else {
        chatMessages.append(ChatMessage(message: (textField.text)!, dateSent: NSDate()))
        textField.text = ""
        //reload table data
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    return true
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    messageTextField.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: Delete derived data,clean and run.

Comment: It still doesn't work

Comment: Put a breakpoint in viewDidLoad and make sure messageTextField isn't nil when you're setting the delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... Its really dumb.

Just return true instead of false in `textFieldShouldEndEditing`